# Even when I convert an str to int it still says it's a str

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, int, port-scanning

I am trying to make a port scanner where the user can type a range of ports to scan on a host, I convert the input from str to int for range but it still says it's an str. Here is my code:

```
os.system('cls')
host = raw_input('Enter hostname or IP address: ')
target = socket.gethostbyname(host)
# converts hostname to IP address

portRange1 = raw_input("Please enter the first number (x) in your range (x, y): ")
portRange2 = raw_input("Please enter the second number (y) in your range (" + portRange1 + ", y): ")
# asks user for range of ports to scan

portRange1 = int(portRange1)
portRange2 = int(portRange2)
# converts variables from str to int

os.system('cls')
# clears console screen

print 'Starting scan on host ' +  target
for port in range(portRange1 + ", " + portRange2):  
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((target, port))
    if result == 0:
        print "Port {}:      Open".format(port)
sock.close()
choice()
# scans for ports 0-1025 on host

choice()
```

And my error is:

```
  File "swisshack_W2.py", line 61, in portScanner
for port in range(portRange1, ", ", portRange2):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

Comment: `", "` is not an integer.

Comment: `for port in range(portRange1 + ", " + portRange2): `
`", "` is whats messing with you i think

Comment: Also, the code you posted doesn't match the error message you posted.

Answer (score 2):

When you add ints to a string, `", "`, you get a string. The `range()` method takes integer arguments.

`for port in range(portRange1, portRange2 + 1):`

Play around with the python interactive interpreter to try out pieces of code.

`help(range)`

```
class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
 |  to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
 |  start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
 |  These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
 |  When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :).